# How to copy values from one table to other table with some additional data

Tags: mysql

There are two tables:

First named Logins with content:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| id           | password                                       |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Ann          | {SSHA}XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  |
| John         | {SSHA}YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY  |
| Walter       | {SSHA}ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ  |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Second named Mailbox with content:

```
+-----------------+------------+-------+---------------------+-----------++----------+
| username        | password   | name  | mailbox_path_prefix | quota     |  domain   |
+-----------------+------------+-------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| lucas@mail.com  | {SSHA}XXXX | lucas | /var/vmail/         | 104857600 |  mail.com |
+-----------------+------------+-------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have to copy data from first table to second.
for example:

1) username from id at first table is Ann, I need to add @mail.com, result should be: Ann@mail.com
2) password will be copied as it is.
3) name will be copied from id at first table as it is 
4) mailbox_path_prefix, quota and domain will be the same at all rows;

Only the way I can do is:

```
INSERT INTO Mailbox (name,password)
SELECT id, password
FROM Logins;
```

I don't know how to join login with @mail.com and insert other values.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO Mailbox (username, password, name, mailbox_path_prefix, quota, domain)
SELECT
    CONCAT(id, '@mail.com'),
    password,
    id,
    'var/vmail/',
    104857600,
    'mail.com'
FROM Logins;
```

The only possibly non self-explanatory part of the above is the usage of `CONCAT` to build the username.  Also note that we may select a constant value (e.g. a string literal or a number) if we want to insert that same value for all rows.

Comment: Better still to establish the constants as table defaults, so you can exclude them from the `INSERT` query entirely.